# ios - what locale would return nil date for this dateformat - ""yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSSZ""

Tags: ios, nsdateformatter

We experienced a crash on a particular device and I think the reason is due to DateFormatter not able to parse the date and returning nil.

The exact format that we use is - yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSSZ

and the date string we want to parse is - 2018-04-19T15:48:00.000Z

I tried many combinations of language, region and time format (12/24) hour.
But, not able to reproduce the issue.

I know I need to set locale to "en_US_POSIX" which I wasn't doing earlier.

But, I would like to reproduce the issue first.

Does any one know for which setting of language, region this problem would occur?

Any help is highly appreciated.

The device (where crash occurred) has 11.3.0 version installed

Thank you.

Comment: Did you set Date formatter behavior?. if not then set it -->[dateFormatter setFormatterBehavior:NSDateFormatterBehavior10_4];

Comment: Thank you for your comment. However, I would like to reproduce the issue before making a fix. Do you know how can I reproduce the issue?